# PHP Script terminating too early

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write a very basic PHP script to fetch some information from a database and output it into a table. Here is the code I have written to far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FamInfo from dbCAN</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test PHP page">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>FamInfo from dbCAN</h1>
    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <th>Family ID</th><th>Signature Domain</th><th>class</th><th>note</th><th>activity</th>
        <?php
            include '/vars.php'; // fixed, no change
            $conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db,$conn);
            $result = mysql_query("select * from FamInfo",$conn);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo '<tr>'; // terminates here, at the second quote
                    echo "<td>" . $row["FamID"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["SigDomain"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["class"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["note"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["activity"] . "</td>";
                echo '</tr><br>';
            }
            mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

For some reason, it seems as if the PHP is terminating at the line where I try to echo the table row, which means I'm not getting and of the values I need. Here's an image of what the output looks like: [image: sorry about the funky highlighting]

Does anyone know why this is happening, or what a potential solution is? Thank you for your input!

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon in ` include '/vars.php'`

Comment: From what I can see none of your PHP is executing. Are you sure your server supports PHP?

Comment: @andrewsi maybe post that as the answer, as that's what it is

Comment: @andrewsi Thank you, I popped that in but nothing changed.

Comment: Seems like something wrong with vars.php or maybe this is because no ";" at the end of inclusion row.

Comment: Does your file end in .php?

Comment: @derekwolf - in that case, turn on error reporting and see what happens

Comment: Its probably bailing on a fatal error somewhere. Turn on error reporting and display errors and see that messages you get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not ending the `include '/vars.php'` statement with a semi-colon. You should also enclose the header row in row tags, `<tr></tr>`.

Also no need to have `<br>` tag between table rows.

You might have an error in `/vars.php` as well. Have you checked the error logs? You might post that code too.

Comment: Enclosing the headers in <tr></tr> helped the formatting, but the PHP still doesn't appear to work properly.

Comment: You might have an error in '/vars.php' too. You can post that code too if you'd like. See if you have any errors being logged.

Comment: Yes, it is a .php :P I'm getting a fatal error when I run it from bash: Call to undefined function mysql_connect().

Comment: vars.php doesn't contain any errors. it's literally just 4 lines of variable declarations that i didn't want visible to anyone accessing the page. for example, '$hostname = "127.0.0.1"'

Comment: Ah, there ya go. You might have the extension disabled/commented-out in your php.ini file. You can enable the extension, but I would take @MadaraUchiha's advice and use PDO or MySqli, because MySql extension is deprecated.

Comment: Just fyi, the `error_log` directive in php.ini will let you specify a path/file to log php warnings/errors ^^

Comment: My server is running PHP5, and it looks like I may be forced to use PDO or MySqli. I just learned to use mysql_connect in a class last semester, that really pisses me off that it's deprecated. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like your PHP code is not being executed but is instead being rendered as text. There a couple of reasons for that:

1) If your file is a .html file you need to enable php parsing in your apache configuration to allow it to support php parsing within html files. This is assuming you are using apache as your webserver. If not there are ways to enable PHP parsing from with html files. For Apache, check your .htaccess, httpd.conf, or wherever else you have your mimetypes defined and add:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

2) If you have a .php file and are seeing this you need to make sure that PHP is enabled on your environment.

3) if all is well and you are seeing this then the issue MAY BE an unclosed php tag (?>) somewhere, most likely that vars.php file, which is throwing stuff off.

If none of these suggestions make sense then I am at a loss but if you provide more information I can assist you further.